# Method is not getting called twice in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, instagram

I am working on Instagram integration in IOS.Every thing goes well.I am geting the feeds of the user and displaying them on tableview and also in scroll view.Here the user is allowed to refresh the page.While refreshing the method is not getting called and its getting crashed because of zero objects in array.I had used the following code to call the method.

```
-(IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender
{
        AppDelegate* appDelegate_new = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
      [appDelegate_new.instagram authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"comments", @"likes", nil]];


      if ([appDelegate.instagram isSessionValid]) {

    //  NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad Session Valid");

          loginView.hidden=YES;
          crossButton.hidden=YES;
          settingsButton.hidden=NO;
          noticeView.hidden=YES;

          [self.view addSubview:feedsView];
         // [self.logOutView removeFromSuperview];
          self.feedsView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 300);
          NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"users/self/feed", @"method", nil];
          [appDelegate.instagram requestWithParams:params
                                    delegate:self];
    } 
}
```

The called method was like this

```
      - (void)request:(IGRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
      {

          [self performSelector:@selector(startspinner) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
          self.data = (NSMutableArray *)[result objectForKey:@"data"];
        // NSLog(@"Data Count is %@",[self.data description]);
          createdArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        //*****Here I am performing Json Parsing******//

      }
```

I am calling the above request method again while refreshing

```
    - (void)dropViewDidBeginRefreshing:(ODRefreshControl *)refreshControl
      {
            [createdArray removeAllObjects];

            NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"users/self/feed", @"method", nil];
            [appDelegate.instagram requestWithParams:params
                                delegate:self];
            [self performSelector:@selector(refreshData) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
      }
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong.Correction appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: which method you are calling every time?

Comment: @Sunny   Sorry for the late reply..Was in meeting... I am calling - "(void)request:(IGRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result" every time..

Comment: Why do you call requestDidLoad at all? Shouldn't that be called by the request when the requrest is eventually finished? And where and when do you get the crash?

Comment: Its is in Table view...if array count is zero then its getting crashed.Its because I am parsing the data that request method itself.But where its not getting called @HermannKlecker

Answer (score 0):

Try it....

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(showTime)
                               userInfo:NULL
                                repeats:YES];

- (void)showTime
{
    NSLog(@"Method called");
}
```

Use NSTimer for call method frequently.
Hope i helped.

Comment: Ur answer is out of my requirement dude.. @Chirag

Comment: @Jack1231 : You can call method many times using my answer. What you exactly want?

Comment: its calls as per the mentioned time..But it should be called when ever I tap on refresh button.. @Chirag

Comment: @Jack1231 : set time 0.01 it's called instantly.

Comment: @Jack1231 : Add nstimer code into refresh button and it will worked.

Comment: my issue is solved..I dont knw why it has not called.I put break points and checked.From then it has been calling.Sounds weird but it was solved like this only.. @Chirag Pipaliya